# VB.net error conversion from string to byte is not valid

Tags: vb.net

[Breakpoint Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuRSa.png) Dim txtval as byte = splitline (50) 
Works fine when the form first loads

On the form there is a button to refresh where it runs the routine again to read from txt file refreshing the data.

The declaration then errors out on the txt file line (0) that contains the headers(a string value) . Err=  conversion from string to byte is not valid

What I've tried :

To declare the variable as object
On error resume next 
On error goto

Any suggestions .

```
    Do While StrTxtScheduleStreamR1.Peek() > -1
        Dim textline As String = StrTxtScheduleStreamR1.ReadLine
        'Header Level
        Dim splitline As String() = Split(textline, vbTab)

        'Sub level

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim WIPsplitOrder As String = splitline(WIPRptOrder - 1) ' Production Order
        Dim WIPSplitOpStat As String = splitline(WIPRptOpStatus - 1) ' Operation Status (REL,CRTD)
        Dim WIPSplitWCDesc As String = splitline(WIPRptWCDesc - 1) ' Workcenter Description (KIT STATION)
        Dim WIPSplitWorkCenter As String = splitline(WIPRptWcenter - 1) ' Workcenter Number (101)
        Dim MatShtOrder As String = splitline(MatShtRptOrder - 1) ' Multilevel Production Order
        Dim MatShtSmpDelDate As String = splitline(MatShtRptDelDate - 1) 'Multilevel Delivery Dates
        Dim ConfRptOrder As String = splitline(CnfRptOrder - 1) ' Production Order Confirmation Report
        Dim ConfRptWCDesc As String = splitline(CnfRptWCDesc - 1) ' Workcenter Description - Confirmation Report
        Dim WIPsplitWorksOrder As String = splitline(WIPRptWorksOrder - 1) ' Works Order - Order Book
        Dim WIPsplitEquiptDesc As String = splitline(WIPRptEquiptDesc - 1) ' Equiptment Description
        Dim WipsplitValClass As String = splitline(WipRptValClass - 1) ' Equiptment Type - Order Book
        Dim WipsplitOrdQty As String = splitline(WipRptOrdQty - 1) ' Outstanding Order Qty - Order Book
        Dim txtval1 As byte = splitline(50 ) ' Remaining Production Hours - Order Book
        Dim txtval2 As byte = splitline(51 ) - WipsplitRemCap ' All Op Calc Production Hours - Order Book
        Dim BUFD As Date = splitline(32 - 1)
        Dim WipsplitSerialNo As String ' Serial Number - Order Book
        Dim WIPsplitOpInfo As String = splitline(WIPRptOpInfo - 1) 'Production Operation Description - Order Book
        Dim SearchSpecialPaintWC
```

Comment: `Dim txtval as byte = split line (50)` works fine? How?

Comment: I have update original post to include code, The txtfile is parsed into a datatable for sorting then loaded into Datagridview , On Load the values populate fine when its refreshed the code breaks on 2 lines where the byte var are declared

Comment: **NEVER** use `On Error Resume Next`. As for the issue, what does `splitline(50)` contain? Have you even looked?  If it doesn't contain a text representation of a number in the range 0 to 255 then why is it not obvious why it cannot be converted to a `Byte`?

Comment: contains numbers ranging 0 -20 only , the headers however are strings say "AnotherColumn" this is where the issue is

Comment: @L.Young  `Dim txtval1 As byte = CType(splitline(50), Byte)`. This looks like a port from VB6. This has to be considered a patch. Review your code. You have already been told: remove any On Error Resume Next.